# How to get the browser calculated hashes for blocked scripts when a CSP header or meta tag is present in blazor wasm

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, blazor, content-security-policy, blazor-webassembly

I'm applying CSP for my `.net 5.0 blazor wasm` app. I used [official Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/content-security-policy?view=aspnetcore-5.0#apply-the-policy) as reference. Here is the `meta` tag that I have added to my `index.html`

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
      content="base-uri 'self';
               block-all-mixed-content;
               img-src data: https:;
               object-src 'self';
               script-src 'self'
                          'unsafe-inline'
                          'unsafe-eval';
               style-src 'self'
                         'unsafe-inline';
               upgrade-insecure-requests;">
```

If you see that I have removed `SHA hash` from `script-src` in the above code. All works fine. However I noticed from the docs that to get the `SHA hash` the below steps needs to be followed.

**To obtain SHA hashes for additional inline scripts:**

- Apply the CSP shown in the Apply the policy section.
- Access the browser's developer tools console while running the app locally. The browser calculates and displays hashes for blocked scripts when a CSP header or meta tag is present.
- Copy the hashes provided by the browser to the `script-src` sources. Use single quotes around each hash.

As per the second step, when I run the app I don't see any `SHA hash` from browser console.

**Here is the console screen print:**

[image: Browser Console Screen Print]

Please assist me on how to get the `SHA hash` that I can add in my `script-src`

Comment: Only Chrome browser calcs hashes and shows those in the console. A little problem is that Chrome calcs hashes not only for inline scripts but for inline event handlers and javascript-navigation too.

Comment: This is my Chrome browser console. But cannot find hash in console.

Comment: That's because there is not any CSP violations. Remove 'unsafe-inline' token from CSP and you'll see.